# moving free space before other partition (to resize the root part.)

Tags: partition, gparted

it is possible to move some partition(entire) before another? 
I need to resize my root partition, but the free space is too far away.(I want to move the free space near the root part.)

Can this be done somehow, or have I to backup the data and start from begining?

[image: GParted screenshot showing current disk layout]

Comment: How much free space do you have vs. the size of your partitions?

Comment: [gparted-screenshot](http://imgur.com/enNIPrYl.png)

it look like this, 11gb freespace, thanks for reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think most of the partition management programs for Linux will move a partition unless there is no overlap, and you can't do that because the ~90.8G extended partition (sda2) will not fit inside the ~11.7G free space. (You can't just move swap, sda5, because of how extended partitions work).

*Please read and understand the whole thing before starting. And also, **make a backup.** Just in case.*

What you could do though, is create a a new primary partition, sda3, for the free space. Then use that as a physical volume for LVM. Use LVM to create a volume group with it, then create a logical volume on that. Copy your root filesystem over. This is probably best done from a Live CD/USB.

Then you need to get the system to boot off your logical volume. Hopefully that is as simple as changing `/etc/fstab` (on the copy on the LV), chrooting to that copy, rebuilding the initramfs, and then finally running `update-grub`. That'll hopefully give you a grub menu with two choices of what to boot—both the install on `/dev/sda1` and on your logical volume.

Reboot to the logical volume. Be very sure you've booted from that, not sda1 (and that the copy worked!). Now you can turn `sda1` in to a physical volume, and add it to the same volume group.

You've now got LVM combining `sda1` and your new `sda3` into one "partition." It doesn't matter that they're not contiguous on disk; you can `lvextend` your logical volume (with the system running, even) to add more space to your rootfs.

The above requires a fair bit of Linux experience—**you may find backing up and reinstalling easier.** If you do, I recommend you use LVM when you re-install. It makes growing/shrinking partitions *trivial*, and growing can almost always be done with the system up.

Comment: thanks for a big reply. I need to read more about primary/extanded/LVM, but the reainstall seems to do more clean job here. Thanks ones again.